# Pacotes do Scapy

Tags: python

Eu estou com algumas dúvidas que não consigo sanar sobre o `scapy`, vocês poderiam me ajudar por favor?

Dúvidas:

1. Para declarar um pacote no Scapy eu faço: `pck = IP()/TCP()`. Com isso eu posso consultar as camadas de `pkt`, com por exemplo: `pkt[IP]` ou `pkt[0]`, ai surge uma dúvida:

   - Que tipo de dado é `pkt`? Um dicionário? Como ele usa uma classe como index(no caso IP) ou um número?
2. Como o Scapy trata o `"/"` de `IP()/TCP()` para que o Python não entenda como o divisor?

Answer (score 0):

Aqui ele fala um pouco.

http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#stacking-layers

1.
Para o tipo tenta dá um

```
print(type(pkt))
```

Mas na doc quando instancia um IP ele retorna um `<IP ... >`

2.
Mas com relação ao operador, muito provavelmente no código houve sobrecarga de operadores, sobrescrevendo o comportamento padrão da divisão usando o Data Model do python [1] .

Referência :

[1] [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**truediv**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__truediv__)

Comment: Ah entendi, legal. Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Só uma coisa, referente à index que, no caso pkt usa, essa index seria a própria classe IP, pois não é uma string como nos dicionários? Vi que da pra usar número como index também.